# [Dart]-what datra type is this list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, maps

If I'm to create a list as below,

```
      "quizz_answer": [
            {
              "option_id": 1,
              "is_selected": false
            },
            {
              "option_id": 2,
              "is_selected": true
            },
            {
              "option_id": 3,
              "is_selected": true
            },
            {
              "option_id": 4,
              "is_selected": false
            },
        ],
```

can you tell me what data type the list should be

Comment: List<Map<dynamic,bool>> dynamicList = []; you can do like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable). Create some Dart object and convert them in to json.

And [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) is better too.

Here is an [article](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) show you how to use code generation and json serialize in dart.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom object. Then use a parse json function to manage it.

It’s better if you understand what is object oriented programming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).